# javascript - How to group list of objects based on key and merge the results

Tags: javascript

My input array :

```
const inputAr = [
    {name: "Day", Food: 1},
    {name: "Day", Drink: 2},
    {name: "Day", Sleep: 7},
    {name: "Week", Food: 5},
    {name: "Week", Drink: 5},
    {name: "Week", Sleep: 12},
    {name: "Month", Food: 10},
    {name: "Month", Drink: 2},
    {name: "Month", Sleep: 2},
]
```

Desired output

```
const desiredOut = [
    {
        name: "Day", Food: 1, Drink: 2, Sleep: 7
    },
    {
        name: "Week", Food: 5, Drink: 5, Sleep: 12
    },
    {
        name: "Month", Food: 10, Drink: 2, Sleep: 2
    },
]
```

So far I have managed to group my input array but key but I am not sure how to achieve the desired output.

My code so far

```
const groupedResults = inputAr.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
    (result[currentValue["name"]] = result[currentValue["name"]] || []).push(
        currentValue
    );
    return result;
}, {});
```

The output shown below is not what I want to achieve

```
// groupedReults
[
    {
        Day: [
            {name: "Day", Food: 1},
            {name: "Day", Drink: 2},
            {name: "Day", Sleep: 7},
        ],
        Week: [
            {name: "Week", Food: 5},
            {name: "Week", Drink: 5},
            {name: "Week", Sleep: 12},
        ],
        Month : [
            {name: "Month", Food: 10},
            {name: "Month", Drink: 2},
            {name: "Month", Sleep: 2},
        ]
    }
]
```

link to reproduce instantly: https://jsfiddle.net/21arxkc6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for collecting the groups and extract `name` from the object and assign the rest to the object in the group.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "Day", Food: 1 }, { name: "Day", Drink: 2 }, { name: "Day", Sleep: 7 }, { name: "Week", Food: 5 }, { name: "Week", Drink: 5 }, { name: "Week", Sleep: 12 }, { name: "Month", Food: 10 }, { name: "Month", Drink: 2 }, { name: "Month", Sleep: 2 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { name, ...o }) => {
        Object.assign(r[name] = r[name] || { name }, o);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but when I run this on my react app I get an error like : "Support for the experimental syntax 'logicalAssignment' isn't currently enabled". Weird

Comment: just take the old assignment: `r[name] = r[name] || { name }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement that using `Array.reduce` and `Array.findIndex`.

```js
const inputAr = [
    {name: "Day", Food: 1},
    {name: "Day", Drink: 2},
    {name: "Day", Sleep: 7},
    {name: "Week", Food: 5},
    {name: "Week", Drink: 5},
    {name: "Week", Sleep: 12},
    {name: "Month", Food: 10},
    {name: "Month", Drink: 2},
    {name: "Month", Sleep: 2},
];

const output = inputAr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const { name: curName, ...rest } = cur;
  const existedIndex = acc.findIndex(({ name }) => name === curName);
  if (existedIndex >= 0) {
    acc[existedIndex] = { ...acc[existedIndex], ...rest };
  } else {
    acc.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is it broken down:

1. Group the items by their name and within each group apply the key-value pairs
2. Map the groups to objects with their group as the `name` and the rest of their values as key-value pairs

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Day",   Food:  1 }, { name: "Day",   Drink: 2 }, { name: "Day",   Sleep:  7 },
  { name: "Week",  Food:  5 }, { name: "Week",  Drink: 5 }, { name: "Week",  Sleep: 12 },
  { name: "Month", Food: 10 }, { name: "Month", Drink: 2 }, { name: "Month", Sleep:  2 }
];
    
const groups = data.reduce((groups, { name, ...rest }) =>
  ({ ...groups, [name]: { ...(groups[name] || {}), ...rest } }), {});

console.log(groups);

const result = Object.entries(groups).map(([name, values]) =>
  ({ name, ...values }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here it is again, in one line:

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Day",   Food:  1 }, { name: "Day",   Drink: 2 }, { name: "Day",   Sleep:  7 },
  { name: "Week",  Food:  5 }, { name: "Week",  Drink: 5 }, { name: "Week",  Sleep: 12 },
  { name: "Month", Food: 10 }, { name: "Month", Drink: 2 }, { name: "Month", Sleep:  2 }
];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((groups, { name, ...rest }) =>
    ({ ...groups, [name]: { ...(groups[name] || {}), ...rest } }), {}))
  .map(([name, values]) => ({ name, ...values }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

And the code golf... `r=Object.entries(data.reduce((g,{name:n,...o})=>({...g,[n]:{...(g[n]||{}),...o}}),{})).map(([n,v])=>({name:n,...v}))` (116 bytes)